# Decisions and if method

Tags: java, if-statement

Question in book:

Write a program that translates a letter grade into a number grade. Letter grades are `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `F`, possibly followed by `+` or `–`. Their numeric values are `4`, `3`, `2`, `1`, and `0`. There is no `F+` or `F–`. A `+` increases the numeric value by `0.3`, a `–` decreases it by `0.3`. However, an `A+` has value `4.0`.

Enter a letter grade: `B-` The numeric value is `2.7`.
Use a class Grade with a method `getNumericGrade`.

So my question is : I know my code is right, I can run it. But I was curious whether there is a shortcut or a better version of this code that makes it look more professional and easier to read. Any suggestions or examples would greatly be appreciated.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class grade
{
    private double numericValue = 0;
    private String grade = "";

    public grade()
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.print("Enter Grade: ");
        grade = in .nextLine();
    }

    public double getNumericGrade()
    {

        if (grade.equals("A+") || grade.equals("A"))
        {
            numericValue = 4.0;
        }
        else if (grade.equals("A-"))
        {
            numericValue = 3.7;
        }
        else if (grade.equals("B+"))
        {
            numericValue = 3.3;
        }
        else if (grade.equals("B"))
        {
            numericValue = 3.0;
        }
        else if (grade.equals("B-"))
        {
            numericValue = 2.7;
        }
        else if (grade.equals("C+"))
        {
            numericValue = 2.3;
        }
        else if (grade.equals("C"))
        {
            numericValue = 2.0;
        }
        else if (grade.equals("C-"))
        {
            numericValue = 1.7;
        }
        else if (grade.equals("D+"))
        {
            numericValue = 1.3;
        }
        else if (grade.equals("D"))
        {
            numericValue = 1.0;
        }
        else if (grade.equals("F"))
        {
            numericValue = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Letter not in grading system");
        }
        return numericValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried splitting the "grade name" up into a letter part and a modifier part and then combining them?

Comment: There is also switch-case with String from Java 7.

Comment: i think he is trying to learn if statement first

Comment: Sounds like a perfect question for codereview.SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define the mappings and rules separately:

```
public static enum Grade {

    // Letter grades are A, B, C, D, and F
    // Their numeric values are 4, 3, 2, 1, and 0

    A(4),B(3),C(2),D(1),F(0);

    public final double score;

    private Grade(double d) {
        this.score = d;
    }

    // Grades are possibly followed by + or –
    // There is no F+ or F–
    // a + increases the numeric value by 0.3, a – decreases it by 0.3
    // However, an A+ has value 4.0

    public double getModifiedScore(char sign) {
        switch (sign) {
            case '+':
                return score + (score < 4 && score > 0 ? 0.3 : 0);
            case '-':
                return score + (score > 0 ? -0.3 : 0);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid sign");
        }
    }
}
```

Then just use them (example assumes you have validated the input):

```
public static double getNumericGrade(String s){
    Grade g = Grade.valueOf(s.substring(0, 1));
    if(s.length() > 1){
        return g.getModifiedScore(s.charAt(1));
    }else {
        return g.score;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use a lookup table:

```
private final static Map<String,Double> gradeLookup = 
   new HashMap<String, Double>();

gradeLookup.put("A-", 3.7);

numericValue = gradeLookup.get(grade);
```

Another good option is a switch statement, which as of Java 7 finally works with Strings.

Both options give you built-in input validation, so that the user cannot enter things like 'G' or 'F+' or 'foo'.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to store entire strings like `"A+"` and `"B-"`, since we know before hand what the `+` and `-` should mean in terms of the score. It's just a waste of space to store all possible grades.

Comment: We also know beforehand what `A` or `B` should mean in terms of score. I'd go "all-in" on the table, no need to complicate it again by adding additional calculations later.

Comment: "There is no F+ or F–. .... However, an A+ has value 4.0." So +/- is *not* independent of the letter. Definitely lookup table with all these special cases.

Comment: I agree with @Thilo it is best to keep it dead simple.. No point complicating what is essentially a lookup table..

Comment: The only reason to split it up would be if you want to make it a multidimensional array instead of a simple hash table..

Comment: I still *entirely* disagree. To me, it seems much more appropriate to put just the raw grades in a table and handle the logic of +/- elsewhere. This is also more suitable if additional grades are ever added, or if the way +/- works is altered in any way (e.g. it is decided that 0.4 should be added/subtracted instead of 0.3).

Comment: @arshaji: I'd only consider that if the +/- calculation was truly independent from the grade lookup. As it is, it is highly coupled. I'd choose algorithmic simplicity over hard-to-maintain code.

Comment: The actual grade is independent from +/- except for the special case of `"A+"`, though.

Comment: @arshajii and F, both of which make your code harder to read than the OPs

Comment: If we need to scale to 100s of grades perhaps the algorithm approach might be better, but for such cases simplicity is best..

Comment: @KarthikT For the reasons I mentioned in my previous comment, I believe that this approach will be more difficult to manage in the long run. Essentially, we are hardcoding all of the grade/score pairs here, which I don't think is a good idea especially since they follow a distinct pattern as they do here (*even* if there are some exceptions to this pattern). In any case, clearly there isn't a definitive resolution here, so I suppose we can just agree to disagree, but for the reasons I described, I continue to stand by my viewpoint.

Comment: @arshajii Your point is that if there is a grading change, the lookup table will need to change. That would be valid if a change was likely and time consuming. But A+ to F- grading is unlikely to change. There is no letter before A. F is already given a value of 0 and the "-" rule is deactivated to prevent negative grades. The only way this grading system changes is if the grading logic changes, in which case the code will have to change even if it is "cleverly" designed to allow new grades. And if there IS a change, changing the look-up tble is easier/faster than changing the algo.

Comment: @Sylverdrag Firstly, I don't mean to come off as stubborn or overly-argumenative, I am enjoying hearing the other side of this discussion. Now, clearly the OP is not going to be managing/updating this code extensively, and so doesn't need to worry about anything ever changing. However, it is best practice to always strive to write code in such a way that it can easily be adapted in the future. If the grading logic changes, we will have to change *every* (or, most) hardcoded grade-score pair here, whereas if we deal with +/- separately, it just comes down to changing one or two relevant...

Comment: (cont.)... numbers. Is this going to make a *big* difference here in particular? More than likely not, but that shouldn't change the approach we choose to take. The way I see it, this approach is hardly better than the OP's current code, which essentially already includes all of the grade/score pairs itself. This just wraps it all in a map.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that maps characters (in this case `A`..`D`,`F`) to the corresponding values (`4`..`0`).

When you process your input:

- if it's only one-character long, just look up the character in the map.
- if there is a `+` or `-` at the end, lookup the first character and deal with the second appropriately (according to the rules you posted, remembering to handle the special cases such as `A+`).

---

You can try something like this:

```
private static final Map<Character, Double> grades = new HashMap<>();
static {
    grades.put('A', 4.0);
    grades.put('B', 3.0);
    grades.put('C', 2.0);
    grades.put('D', 1.0);
    grades.put('F', 0.0);
}

public static double getNumericGrade(String input) {
    if (input == null || input.isEmpty() || input.length() > 2
            || input.matches("F[+-]")
            || !grades.containsKey(input.charAt(0)))  // validate input
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    double val = grades.get(input.charAt(0));

    if (input.length() == 1) {
        return val;
    } else if (input.charAt(1) == '+') {
        return (input.charAt(0) == 'A') ? val : val + 0.3;
    } else if (input.charAt(1) == '-') {
        return val - 0.3;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `switch` - which works with `String` in Java 7.

```
// Yes, I'm passing grade and shadowing numericValue, since those properties
// aren't used anywhere else in the class.
public double getNumericGrade(String grade) {
    double numericValue = 0;

    switch (grade) {
        case "A+":
        case "A":
            numericValue = 4.0;
            break;
        case "A-":
            numericValue = 3.7;
            break;
        case "B+":
            numericValue = 3.3;
            break;
        case "B":
            numericValue = 3.0;
            break;
        case "B-":
            numericValue = 2.7;
            break;
        case "C+":
            numericValue = 2.3;
            break;
        case "C":
            numericValue = 2.0;
            break;
        case "C-":
            numericValue = 1.7;
            break;
        case "D+":
            numericValue = 1.3;
            break;
        case "D":
            numericValue = 1.0;
            break;
        case "F":
            numericValue = 0;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Letter not in grading system");
            break;
    }
    return numericValue;
}
```

...but that reads pretty verbosely.

Another alternative approach is to take what rules we have about numeric grades, and write something a little more terse.

- If the grade is some letter point, it is a whole number (A = 4, B = 3, C = 2, D = 1, F = 0).
- If the grade has a minus attached to it, the value is the difference of the whole number and 0.3.
- If the grade has a plus attached to it, the value is the sum of the whole number and 0.3.

Here's a solution, which makes use of those rules.  It may read a little more verbose and might not be all that different than the switch, but it's another way to write it.

```
public double getNumericGradeRefactored(String grade) {
    Map<Character, Double> gradeMap = new HashMap<Character, Double>(){{
        put('A', 4.0);
        put('B', 3.0);
        put('C', 2.0);
        put('D', 1.0);
        put('F', 0.0);
    }};

    // split result
    char[] gradeParts = grade.toCharArray();
    double result = gradeMap.get(gradeParts[0]);
    if(gradeParts.length > 1) {
        switch(gradeParts[1]) {
            case '+':
                result += 0.3;
                break;
            case '-':
                result -= 0.3;
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd deal with the '+' or '-' separately.

Check for the letter, then add or subtract the grade value appropriately if it contains a '+' or '-'.

EDIT: Personally, I prefer switch-case to long if-elseif statements, but either one will work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Thilos suggestion as to how to store the actual data, I would like to add that in such cases, you don't want to store both, in this case, `String` and `int` version of the data, unless performance is EXTREMELY critical.

While this doesnt look like a big deal now, in many cases, you run the risk of loosing sync between them, i.e `String` says one thing and the `int` says another, and you run into bugs due to this.

And your constructor shouldnt prompt for input, unless that becomes very common.. it is cleaner to take a `String`.